# Where do I get Java default Library on windows?

Tags: java

I couldn't find HttpURLConnection in my java environment, and I wonder how to get that class.
How to get Java Basic Library on windows?
I've searched for that for 2 hours.

e.g:

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

Comment: Do you have JDK attached to your IDE? Look for: how to add JAVA_HOME env.

Comment: That's [part of the JDK](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/package-summary.html) if you have a JDK, you don't need to download anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you can find java default library on your system location as mentioned below
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_151\lib(follow this path)